# RestAssured Multipart - Concatenate multiple multiPart values into a single value

Tags: java, multipartform-data, rest-assured, selenium-java

I am having multiple API tests which have different sets of multipart input values which vary dynamically,
I want to create 1 common function which can accept these varying multiple multipart into a single multipart line so that I don't have to create multiple response functions to accept these varying values.

```
public test1(){
| KEY| VALUE |
|key1 | value1|
|key2 | value2|
|key3 | value3|
}

public test2(){
| KEY| VALUE |
|key1 | value1|
|key2 | value2|
}

public test3(){
| KEY| VALUE |
|key1 | value1|
|key2 | value2|
|key3 | value3|
|key4 | value4|
|key5 | value5|
}
```

**Actual:**

```
 public void common() {
    Response response = given().urlEncodingEnabled(true).config(RestAssured.config()
                            .encoderConfig(encoderConfig().encodeContentTypeAs("multipart/form-data", ContentType.TEXT)))
                            .multiPart("key1","value1")
                            .multiPart("key2","value2")
                            .multiPart("key3","value3")
                            .multiPart("key4","value4")
                            .multiPart("key5","value5")
                            .config(RestAssured.config()
                            .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
                            .headers(request.getHeaders())
                            .post(path);
}
```

**Expected logic something like which combines all multipart values into a single function:**

```
 public void common() {
    given().urlEncodingEnabled(true).config(RestAssured.config()
    .encoderConfig(encoderConfig().encodeContentTypeAs("multipart/form-data", ContentType.TEXT)))
    .multiPart("key1","value1";"key2","value2";"key3","value3";"key4","value4";"key5","value5")
    .config(RestAssured.config()
    .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
    .headers(request.getHeaders())
    .post(path);
}
```

Any pointers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like below should match your use cases, you can add a helper method like buildMultiParts below which  will take var args of type string and return the modified request with added multiparts

```
import static io.restassured.config.EncoderConfig.encoderConfig;
import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;
import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.http.ContentType;
import io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl;
import io.restassured.specification.RequestSpecification;

public class MultiPartExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RestAssured.baseURI = "http://example.com"; // Set your base URL

        RequestSpecification requestSpecification = buildMultiParts("key1", "value1", "key2",
            "value2", "key3", "value3", "key4", "value4", "key5", "value5");
        ((RequestSpecificationImpl) requestSpecification).getMultiPartParams().forEach(
            System.out::println);
        requestSpecification.urlEncodingEnabled(true).config(RestAssured.config().encoderConfig(
                encoderConfig().encodeContentTypeAs("multipart/form-data", ContentType.TEXT)))
            .headers("sample", "sample").post("/path");
    }


    private static RequestSpecification buildMultiParts(String... keyValues) {
        if (keyValues.length % 2 != 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid number of arguments");
        }
        int numPairs = keyValues.length / 2;
        RequestSpecification specification = given();
        for (int i = 0; i < numPairs; i++) {
            int index = i * 2;
            String key = keyValues[index];
            String value = keyValues[index + 1];
            specification.multiPart(key, value);
        }

        return specification;
    }

}
```

You can see the output also with params added

```
controlName=key1, mimeType=text/plain, charset=<none>, fileName=file, content=value1, headers=[:]
controlName=key2, mimeType=text/plain, charset=<none>, fileName=file, content=value2, headers=[:]
controlName=key3, mimeType=text/plain, charset=<none>, fileName=file, content=value3, headers=[:]
controlName=key4, mimeType=text/plain, charset=<none>, fileName=file, content=value4, headers=[:]
controlName=key5, mimeType=text/plain, charset=<none>, fileName=file, content=value5, headers=[:]
```

Comment: Thanks for elaborating and providing a Solution, Appreciate it !! This is exactly what I was looking for !!

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 solutions here (from my view):

1. write a custom function with parameter is a `Map<String,?>`, then foreach the EntrySet of the Map to add multiple `multipart`.
2. Second solution is the same with the first one, but this time, using `varargs` to get dynamic parameter. But the downside is that the data type must be String to both `key` and `value`. It's not dynamic as first solution.

Comment: I think I was not able to explain my Expected result properly, what I meant was I need some logic which will allow me to merge  multiple multipart values into a single value. The multipart function is a default RestAssured method which does not support this and just passing the key-values separated by ; does not work. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Java doesn’t allow ; as a separator, that’s why I suggested 2 other solutions.

Comment: @AutomationEngr check Abhay's answer, that's what I was talking about, solution 2.